# How do I send message from HTML to Python (Flask) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, sockets, server

I need to send string from HTML file to Python(Flask) using JavaScript.

This is my HTML code inside "templates" folder:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="test">Large button</button>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
```

This is my JavaScript code (**`index.js`**) inside "static" folder

```
$(function() {
$('a#test').bind('click', function() {
//var value = document.getElementById("msg").value
    $.getJSON('/run',
        //{val:value},
        function(data) {
        // do nothing
        });
        return false;
  });
});
```

This is the code for my `main.py`

```
from flask import *

#some code

@app.route("/run")
def run():
print("clicked")
return "none"
```

It is supposed to work, but the button doesn't work, "clicked" isn't being printed when the button is being pressed.

Comment: change $('a#test') to $('button#test') or better $('#test')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@geatanoM `change $('a#test') to $('#test')` as there should only ever be one element with test as its id and your trying to call an `a` tag in your code rather than a button

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the issue. I am not familiar with JavaScript :))